# Python Pandas: Compute Consecutive Window Count of Positive Numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count

Say I have a dataframe with:

```
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3   | Col4                |
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+
| A    | 0.532 | -0.234 | 2020-01-01 05:00:00 |
| B    | 0.242 | 0.224  | 2020-01-01 06:00:00 |
| A    | 0.152 | -0.753 | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 |
| C    | 0.149 | 0.983  | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 |
| A    | 0.635 | 0.429  | 2020-01-01 09:00:00 |
| A    | 0.938 | 0.365  | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 |
| C    | 0.293 | 0.956  | 2020-01-02 05:00:00 |
| A    | 0.294 | -0.234 | 2020-01-02 06:00:00 |
| E    | 0.294 | 0.394  | 2020-01-02 07:00:00 |
| D    | 0.294 | 0.258  | 2020-01-02 08:00:00 |
| A    | 0.687 | 0.666  | 2020-01-03 05:00:00 |
| C    | 0.232 | 0.494  | 2020-01-03 06:00:00 |
| D    | 0.575 | 0.845  | 2020-01-03 07:00:00 |
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+
```

I want to count the number of subsequent consecutive positive numbers, until I hit a negative or 0, for Col3 to return:

```
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+------+
| Col1 | Col2  | Col3   | Col4                | Col5 |
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+------+
| A    | 0.532 | -0.234 | 2020-01-01 05:00:00 | 0    | => Number is (-), no value.
| B    | 0.242 | 0.224  | 2020-01-01 06:00:00 | 1    | => Number is (+), next (-), 1.
| A    | 0.152 | -0.753 | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 | 0    | => Number is (-), no value.
| C    | 0.149 | 0.983  | 2020-01-01 08:00:00 | 4    | => Number is (+), next 3 (+), 4.
| A    | 0.635 | 0.429  | 2020-01-01 09:00:00 | 3    | => Number is (+), next 2 (+), 3.
| A    | 0.938 | 0.365  | 2020-01-01 10:00:00 | 2    |
| C    | 0.293 | 0.956  | 2020-01-02 05:00:00 | 1    |
| A    | 0.294 | -0.234 | 2020-01-02 06:00:00 | 0    |
| E    | 0.294 | 0.394  | 2020-01-02 07:00:00 | 5    |
| D    | 0.294 | 0.258  | 2020-01-02 08:00:00 | 4    |
| A    | 0.687 | 0.666  | 2020-01-03 05:00:00 | 3    |
| C    | 0.232 | 0.494  | 2020-01-03 06:00:00 | 2    |
| D    | 0.575 | 0.845  | 2020-01-03 07:00:00 | 1    |
+------+-------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

How can I achieve this efficiently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you just need to count backwards:

```
s = df["Col3"][::-1]

df["New"] = s.groupby((s<0).cumsum()).apply(lambda d: (d>=0).cumsum())

print (df)

   Col1   Col2   Col3                 Col4  New
0     A  0.532 -0.234  2020-01-01 05:00:00    0
1     B  0.242  0.224  2020-01-01 06:00:00    1
2     A  0.152 -0.753  2020-01-01 08:00:00    0
3     C  0.149  0.983  2020-01-01 08:00:00    4
4     A  0.635  0.429  2020-01-01 09:00:00    3
5     A  0.938  0.365  2020-01-01 10:00:00    2
6     C  0.293  0.956  2020-01-02 05:00:00    1
7     A  0.294 -0.234  2020-01-02 06:00:00    0
8     E  0.294  0.394  2020-01-02 07:00:00    5
9     D  0.294  0.258  2020-01-02 08:00:00    4
10    A  0.687  0.666  2020-01-03 05:00:00    3
11    C  0.232  0.494  2020-01-03 06:00:00    2
12    D  0.575  0.845  2020-01-03 07:00:00    1
```

Comment: If I had to group by a set of 2-3 additional columns, how would this work out? Trying to dissect the logic of this line.